# Data binding a Winforms `ComboBox.SelectedItem` seems to not work when the binding implements the Format event handler

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combo box where `SelectedItem` is data bound. I want to display different values on the control from what I store in my model (display: "Comma", model: ","). To translate between the two I implemented handlers for `Binding.Format` and
`Binding.Parse`:

```
// simplified for test case purposes
binding.Format += (s, e) => e.Value = ((string)e.Value == ",") ? "Comma" : "Semicolon";
binding.Parse += (s, e) => e.Value = ((string)e.Value == "Comma") ? "," : ";";
```

When the program is run, I expected the combo box to display "Comma", but it
shows nothing (as its seleceted item) instead.

What am I doing wrong?

## Notes

- A text box (with a similar mapping) shows the correct value.
- Without the mapping (i.e. replacing "," with "Comma" in the model and
  removing the handlers) the combo box shows the expected value.
- I noticed (using a break point) that the `Format` handler is run twice when
  the form is shown, why is it run two times (instead of once)?
- After the form is closed the `Format` handler is run twice again, why is it
  run at all?

## Testcase

```
public class Model
{
    public string Value { get; set; } = ",";
}

[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    var model = new Model();

    var comboBox = new ComboBox() { Dock = DockStyle.Top };
    comboBox.Items.AddRange(new object[] { "Comma", "Semicolon", });
    var binding = new Binding(nameof(ComboBox.SelectedItem), model, nameof(Model.Value));
    binding.Format += (s, e) => e.Value = ((string)e.Value == ",") ? "Comma" : "Semicolon";
    binding.Parse += (s, e) => e.Value = ((string)e.Value == "Comma") ? "," : ";";
    comboBox.DataBindings.Add(binding);

    var textBox = new TextBox() { Dock = DockStyle.Top };
    var binding1 = new Binding(nameof(TextBox.Text), model, nameof(Model.Value));
    binding1.Format += (s, e) => e.Value = ((string)e.Value == ",") ? "Comma" : "Semicolon";
    binding1.Parse += (s, e) => e.Value = ((string)e.Value == "Comma") ? "," : ";";
    textBox.DataBindings.Add(binding1);

    Application.Run(new Form() { Controls = { comboBox, textBox, } });
}
```